# i want to add a floating refresh button in webview app

Tags: android, button

I have made  a Android `WebView` app using `Android Studio`, I want to add a cool floating refresh `Button` , can anyone help me please .

Comment: use swipe to refresh layout and do post some of your code and where you are stuck and the expected result

Comment: Use this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog or this : https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Comment: what about using a `RelativeLayout` ?